# Run Grunt when node server starts

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Is this posible since im not using any framework? I want to grunt taks be started when node js server is started.Should I put something in Gruntfile.js?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it that way: you create a package.json file in wich you'll declare all your dependencies. and also you creat a node start "start app" so once the app started or node started you'll be able to start grunt or whatever you want.